# How does one replace last element of full stack with new element? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, stack

```
public class ourStack1 {
    private int elements[];
    private int index;      // indicate the next position to put a new data
    private int size;
    
    public ourStack1() {
        elements = new int[10];
        index = 0;
        size = 0;
    }
    
    public void push(int value) {
        if(size == 10) {
            System.out.println("Stack is full, no push");
            return;
        }
        elements[index] = value;
        ++index;
        ++size;
    }
    
    public int pop() {
        if(size == 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty, no pop");
            return -1;
        }
        int temp = elements[index - 1];
        --index;
        --size;
        return temp;
    }
    
    public int peek() {
        if(size == 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty, no peek");
            return -1;
        }
        return elements[index - 1];
    }
    
    /*
    public int mySize() {
        // you know how to do this
    }
    */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ourStack1 x = new ourStack1();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            x.push(i);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            System.out.println(x.pop());
    }
}
```

I'm confused on how to overwrite the last element added to the full stack. I want to add element to replace the last element while not exceeding the array size[10]

Comment: I'm very new to coding, I'm currently a college student struggling with online learning.

Comment: "I'm confused on how to overwrite the last element added to the full stack." if I understand you correctly you want to replace element at "top" of the stack. In such case you can simply pop current top element and after that push new one. If that is not what you meant please [edit] your question and add more detail about problem you are facing.

Comment: @pshemo yes you are spot on! that is my question.

Comment: Then like I said, it looks like all you need is to call something like `yourStack.pop();` and after that `yourStack.push(yourNewValue);`.

Comment: where would I put this in the code given? apologies like I said I'm a first year student with online learning. Its been tough, but thank you very much for the help @pshemo

Comment: That depends. Do you want to simply modify top element of some specific set? Then if you have `ourStack1 yourStack = //...create, fill with data` then simply call `yourStack.pop(); yourStack.push(yourNewValue);`. OR maybe you want to add a method to your stack like `updateTopValue(int newValue){...}`? In such case you can implement it like `updateTopValue(int newValue){ check if stack contains any value, if yes pot it. After that push newValue }.` (I used pseudocode for so you could practice expressing your intentions via code yourself).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void replaceLast(int value) {
  if (this.size > 0) {
    this.pop();
  }
  this.push(value);
}
```